# how to turn datetime value ToLocalTime inside member expression?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, expression

I have a member expression (type is System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression {System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression})

I need to compare the "Day" and "Month" of that expression's DateTime value to Today's Day/Month, but *after* converting my expression's value ToLocalTime. I retrieve it from the Database in UTC time, and I need to make the conversion ToLocalTime before doing my expression comparisons.

I have been trying to find a way to do "ToLocalTime" on the expression but I only get errors, below are my latest trials:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime();

//create expressions for day and month
var todayDayExp = Expression.Constant(today.Day);
var todayMonthExp = Expression.Constant(today.Month);

MemberExpression valueToChange = //code that returns memberexpression

//Problem is in line below
var ExpressionValueAfterToLocalTime = Expression.Call(typeof(DateTime), "ToLocalTime", null, valueToChange );

var valueprop = Expression.Property(ExpressionValueAfterToLocalTime , "Value");

var xconnectDayValue = Expression.Property(valueprop, "Day");
var xconnectMonthValue = Expression.Property(valueprop, "Month");


Expression dayComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(
                       xconnectDayValue, todayDayExp);

Expression monthComparisonExpression = Expression.Equal(
                      xconnectMonthValue, todayMonthExp);

Expression finalEx = Expression.AndAlso(dayComparisonExpression, monthComparisonExpression);
```

The error I get is on the line where I try to get ExpressionValueAfterToLocalTime :
"No method 'ToLocalTime' exists on type 'System.DateTime'."

Does anyone know how to achieve this? I need to do "ToLocalTime" on the DateTime value of my member expression.

Comment: That overload of `Expression.Call` is used for invoking *static* methods.  `Parse` is static, but `ToLocalTime` is an instance method.  There are other overloads you can use.  But also, it would be easier to provide a direct answer if you could edit your question to be a *complete* sample please?  As is, it's unclear why you are parsing something you say is already a `DateTime` object instead of a string.  It's also unclear why you need to be dealing with expressions at all.  Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Edited the question, removed the "Parse" line as it was irrelevant, added more explanation as to why I need to do this, I'm forced to use expressions by the technology I'm working with here, hope this helps clarify things

Comment: Getting close to complete, but not quite there.  Could you please complete the line that creates the `MemberExpression` For example, [something like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.memberexpression?view=net-5.0#examples) but adjusted for your use case?  Thanks.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint thank you for trying to help, I figured it out, will add the answer in case it helps someone in the future

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out how to convert a UTC DateTime object of type MemberExpression to local time:

```
            var dateTimeValueMemberExpression = //custom function that gets my datetime member expression

            //gets the value property from my member expression
            var valueprop = Expression.Property(dateTimeValueMemberExpression , "Value");

            //create "MethodInfo" separately to use in the "Expression.Call" function
            MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToLocalTime");
            
            var valueToLocalTimeMethodCallExp = Expression.Call(valueprop, methodInfo);
```

Once I got "valueToLocalTimeMethodCallExp" I was able to access it's "Day" and "Month" properties just fine as below:

```
var xconnectDayValue = Expression.Property(valueToLocalTimeMethodCallExp, "Day");
var xconnectMonthValue = Expression.Property(valueToLocalTimeMethodCallExp, "Month");
```

Comment: Looks nice.  You could also consider using [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) to prevent typos if you have a lot of this type of code.